# Div element is not positioned as sticky

Tags: html, css

Here is `buhehe.de` a simple `div` element on the right  in `<div class="adssec">` and in CSS i wrote  `.adssec {position: sticky !important;}`  but it is not sticked during scrolling.

Wwhat did i wrong?

Comment: show your html and add snippet

Comment: and also give it some dimensions, width and height

Comment: `Here is buhehe.de`.. am sorry.. where? Can't see a 'buhehe.de'

Comment: I think it's http://buhehe.de/

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the threshold at which you want to make it sticky.
From [CSS Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/position-sticky-2/):

> Sticky positioning is a hybrid of relative and fixed positioning. The element is treated as relative positioned until it crosses a specified threshold, at which point it is treated as fixed positioned.

Specify a `top`, `bottom`, `left` or `bottom` value for the sticky element.

Comment: This most probably will be the solution for the OP's question

Comment: when i type .adssec {position: fixed !important;
top:10px !important;}
the div elemtn is disapeared

Comment: it should be `sticky` not `fixed`

Comment: @InteressanteFakten see my answer. which may help you :)

Answer (score 2):

You may use **position:fixed**. or  **position:sticky** like below example.

```css
body
{
  margin: 0 15%;
  background-color: #ecf0f1;
}
div
{
  border: solid #34495e 1px;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin: 0 0 10px 0;
  background-color: white;
}
.fixed, .sticky
{
  font-size: 1.4em;
  padding: 10px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.fixed
{
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #34495e;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 2;
}
.sticky
{
  position: sticky;
  top: 60px;
  background-color: #2ecc71;
}
.container
{
  height: 250px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.out-container
{
  top: 50px;
  background-color: #9b59b6;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
  <body>
 <div class="fixed">
  Fixed Position
 </div>
 <br/><br/><br/>
 <div>
  <h3>
   Some random content for overflowing the entire content.
  </h3>
  <p>
   There are three responses to a piece of design – yes, no, and WOW! Wow is the one to aim for.
  </p>
  <p>
   Software testing is a sport like hunting, it's bughunting.
  </p>
  <p>
   Java is to JavaScript what Car is to Carpet.
  </p>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
   adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation. eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
  </p>
 </div>
 <div class="sticky out-container">
  Sticky Positioning
 </div>
 <div class="container">
  <h3>
   Some random content for overflowing the content of this container.
  </h3>
  <p>
   There are three responses to a piece of design – yes, no, and WOW! Wow is the one to aim for.
  </p>  <p>
   Software testing is a sport like hunting, it's bughunting.
  </p>
  <p>
   Java is to JavaScript what Car is to Carpet.
  </p>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
   adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation. eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
  </p>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
   adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation. eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
  </p>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
   adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation. eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
  </p>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
   adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation. eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
  </p>
 <div>
  <h3>
   Some random content for overflowing the entire content.
  </h3>
  <p>
   There are three responses to a piece of design – yes, no, and WOW! Wow is the one to aim for.
  </p>
  <p>
   Software testing is a sport like hunting, it's bughunting.
  </p>
  <p>
   Java is to JavaScript what Car is to Carpet.
  </p>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
   adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation. eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
  </p>
 </div>
 <div>
  <h3>
   Some random content for overflowing the entire content.
  </h3>
  <p>
   There are three responses to a piece of design – yes, no, and WOW! Wow is the one to aim for.
  </p>
  <p>
   Software testing is a sport like hunting, it's bughunting.
  </p>
  <p>
   Java is to JavaScript what Car is to Carpet.
  </p>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
   adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation. eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
  </p>
 </div>
 <div>
  <h3>
   Some random content for overflowing the entire content.
  </h3>
  <p>
   There are three responses to a piece of design – yes, no, and WOW! Wow is the one to aim for.
  </p>
  <p>
   Software testing is a sport like hunting, it's bughunting.
  </p>
  <p>
   Java is to JavaScript what Car is to Carpet.
  </p>
  <p>
   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.
   adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
   Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation. eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore
  </p>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is wrong. `fixed` and `sticky` are not the same.

Comment: @goediaz i had update the answer.. with both `fixed` and `sticky`

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to just keep an element on the position that you gave it?

In that case `position: fixed` will do the trick.

However, if you're trying to get an element to stay at the top of the page once it reaches the top of the page by scrolling, then you should use `position: sticky`.

**According to the Mozilla developer docs**

> This is an experimental API which should not be used in production code.

**Possible solution without `posistion: sticky`**

Going with some JavaScript would be a far better option here. When the element reaches the top, add `position: fixed` to the styles.

```
window.onscroll = function() {myFunction()};

var div = document.getElementById("myDiv");

var sticky = div.offsetTop;

function myFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
    div.classList.add("sticky")
  } else {
    div.classList.remove("sticky");
  }
}
```